# Detect letter where number was expected

Tags: perl

How can I detect and show an error if someone put a letter and the program expects a number?

Comment: Hi, fasolo. There are lots of ways to accomplish this, so it's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you trying to find out if a variable contains a string or a number? Or are you more concerned with how to present this to the user?

Comment: We also need to see some code. Is this a program the user would run from the command line, a web app, a GUI program or something else?

Comment: @ JSBձոգչ Hi, imagine a calculator. What the program accepts is 2+2, if someone try to put 2+"a" the program show an error.

Comment: Just an "if" with a verification if some input is a letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regexp match makes this easy. Searching for any character which isn't a numeral or an arithmetic symbol:

```
if ( $input =~ /[^0-9+*/-]/ ) {
  print "Incorrect character detected!\n"
}
```

Literally anything which is a letter:

```
if ( $input =~ /[A-Za-z]/ ) {
  print "Incorrect character detected!\n"
}
```